# Why does RabbitMQ Cluster Operator require cluster-scoped read operations on Secrets?

Tags: rabbitmq

We have installed RabbitMQ Cluster Operator on our kubernetes cluster and I noticed that the clusterRole has the resource "secrets" with verbs "get, list, watch, create, delete".

As a central Kubernetes management team in an organization, we would like to give restricted access for Secrets, and just wanted to get an idea around what's the use-case which the operator is supporting.

If I remove the "get" and "list" verbs when the operator is starting it throws the error:

```
Failed to watch *v1.Secret: failed to list *v1.Secret: secrets is forbidden: User \"system:serviceaccount:namespace:rabbitmq-cluster-operator\" cannot list resource \"secrets\" in API group \"\" at the cluster scope\n"
```

Why does it need cluster wide access to secrets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [Kubernetes Operator Pattern](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/extend-kubernetes/operator/), the intention of using an Operator is to act like a "human operator who is managing a service or set of services". That means creating roles and bindings, service and deployment definitions, and - critically - managing configuration and secrets.

The RabbitMQ documentation discusses some of the ways secrets are used, for example [storing instance admin credentials in a known location whenever a new instance is created](https://www.rabbitmq.com/kubernetes/operator/using-operator.html#creds).

> Admin credentials for a RabbitmqCluster are stored in a Kubernetes secret called INSTANCE-default-user, where INSTANCE is the name of the RabbitmqCluster object. Kubernetes encodes secrets using base64.

This alone requires cluster level secret `get, list, create, delete` because the operator does not know ahead of time what namespace instances will be created in.

Without scanning the entire RabbitMQ operator repository it is also common to `watch` secrets for changes so the associated resources can be reloaded or updated with new certificates or credentials automatically.

Most Kubernetes operators can be hardened with more specific RoleBindings such that they are granted secret permissions only in the desired namespaces. This would replace the equivalent ClusterRoleBinding (instead using a RoleBinding in the desired namespace(s)), but allow the permissions to remain as a single ClusterRole for standardisation.

You may be able to bypass your cluster-level permissions error by adding a configuration for `OPERATOR_SCOPE_NAMESPACE` as described in [Cluster Operator Environment Variables](https://www.rabbitmq.com/kubernetes/operator/configure-operator-defaults.html#parameters).

| Variable Name | Effect when set | Effect when not set |
| --- | --- | --- |
| OPERATOR_SCOPE_NAMESPACE | Namespace, or list of namespaces, which the operator will reconcile and watch RabbitmqClusters (independent of installation namespace). Use a comma separator, without spaces e.g. "project-1,project-2,rabbitmq-testing" | All namespaces are watched and reconciled |